# How to show the full description plus examples of a function in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, f#

As you can see, it only shows the summary but with no examples

[image: As]

If I go to the definition:
[image]

How can I make it so it shows the full description + examples? Like in VS Code

[image]

Comment: you click on ctrl and hover upon the function you looking for

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem, it keeps showing only a summary and not the Examples